# How to Insert new element into existed mongodb and uptate existed document from json file?

Tags: python, json, mongodb

I have a problem about python and mongodb. I have an existed mongodb wh and a collection basicdata in it. I want to merge json file into that existed mongodb by key "whID". my code as follows:

```
import json, glob, codecs
from pymongo import MongoClient

directory = 'json/test/211.json'
client = MongoClient("localhost", 27017)
db = client.wh

jsonFiles = glob.glob(directory)
for file in jsonFiles:
     fwhID = file[10:13] #get the file name as whID in a stupid way
     with codecs.open(file,'r',errors='ignore',encoding='utf-8') as json_file:
          json_data = json.load(json_file)
          db.basicdata.update({"whID": fwhID },json_data, {upsert: true})
          print("Processing Json_data: ",file)
     json_file.close()
```

but I got a error message as follow:

```
    db.basicdata.update({"whID": fwhID },json_data, {upsert: true})
NameError: name 'true' is not defined
```

Can anybody could help me? Thanks!!

Comment: in python true should be written with a capital letter `True`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using python to connect to Mongodb. In python true is `True`, In mongodb is `true`.

and change

```
db.basicdata.update({"whID": fwhID },json_data, {upsert: true})
```

to

```
db.basicdata.update({"whID": fwhID },json_data, upsert= true)
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. But I got a new error message: NameError: name 'upsert' is not defined?? What should I do?

Comment: Thanks you very much. I  modify my code and it work!! But I find another problem. I want this json file will be inserted into an existed document, but my code create another new object. That's don't meet my need! Is there any way could meet my need?

Comment: that is what upsert is doing, it creates a new document if does not find a match: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/

Answer (score 0):

I justmodify one line code as follow: 
original

```
db.basicdata.update({"whID": fwhID },json_data, {upsert: true})
```

change to

```
db.basicdata.update( {"whID" : fwhID },{"$set":json_data}, upsert= True)
```

Then It work!
db.basicdata.update( {"whID" : fwhID },{"$set":json_data}, upsert= True)
{"$set":json_data} will put dict into existed document and match the key "whID".